# how to fix 'tunnel server offline: Request failed with status code 502' error of localtunnel

Tags: node.js, npm, localtunnel

I am setting up a microservice. The code is working fine on localhost. To make it accessible to the other computers too I tried npm's localtunnel. Sometimes it used to give 404 error but it was working fine for straight 2 days. But suddenly It started giving 502 'tunnel server offline: Request failed with status code 502, retry 1s' error.

I uninstalled and re-installed localtunnel, 
Rechecked my code on localhost,
To fix 502 error, I cleared the browser's cache and checked firewall status.

While setting up localtunnel I ran following commands on terminal:npm install -g localtunnel,
lt --port 3002 --subdomain user,
sudo npm install --save-dev forever.

I expect the output of lt --port 3002 --subdomain user to be 'your url is: https://user.localtunnel.me', but actual output is 'tunnel server offline: Request failed with status code 502, retry 1s'

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Localtunnel doesn't work anymore. I also got 502 trying to do a simple "lt --port 3000" command.

Looking for workarounds, I found ngrok ([here](https://dashboard.ngrok.com/get-started)). Downloaded it into some folder, opened a terminal in this folder and executed "./ngrok.exe https 3000" and it worked like a charm!

Comment: I tried this solution as well. But for personalized URL they are asking for charges.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way.

The problem:
Once you make your subdomain request, and then terminate it with Ctrl+c. It will terminate on the terminal but, the task still runs on the background.
I solved it by going to task manager, and terminating all task that involve "HOST".
After that, make your request again for subdomain. i.e, lt --port 3002 --subdomain mysubdomain